# Subviews on UICollectionViewCell jumped between cells

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an `UICollectionView` with multiple sections and multiple types of custom cells on it.

But instead of showing the same subviews on each cell of the same type, every time I scroll the section off the screen and back on, only part of the custom cell show the subviews on them.

Please check the screen shots below:

[image] 
[image]

Why is that?

I have registered all kinds of cell in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:normalCellID];
[self registerClass:[BLMineSectionCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:sectionCellID];
[self registerClass:[BLMineOrderCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:orderCellID];
```

And in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` I did:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0 ||
    indexPath.section == 2 ||
    indexPath.section == 4 ||
    indexPath.section == 5)
{
    BLMineSectionCollectionViewCell *sectionCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:sectionCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return sectionCell;
}
else if (indexPath.section == 1)
{
    BLMineOrderCollectionViewCell *orderCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:orderCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIColor *color = nil;
    switch (indexPath.item)
    {
        case 0:
            color = [UIColor redColor];
            break;
        case 1:
            color = [UIColor greenColor];
            break;
        case 2:
            color = [UIColor purpleColor];
            break;
        default:
            color = nil;
            break;
    }
    orderCell.iconImageView.backgroundColor = color;
    orderCell.textLabel.backgroundColor = color;
    return orderCell;
}
else
{
    UIColor *color = nil;
    color = [UIColor blueColor];
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:normalCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = color;
    return cell;
}
```

Please point out my mistakes, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `UICollectionView` is a little bit different from `UITableView` in the point of "re-use" strategy.

When scrolling up and down, `UITableView` would trigger `layoutSubviews` each time a new cell is coming on the screen area while `UICollectionView` would not.

That's why some of the `UICollectionViewCell` did not display the complete subviews above.

What I have done is manually send `setNeedsLayout` message to the cell object to trigger its `layoutSubviews` method.

Comment: Hi @valosip, when I asked this question I was not familiar with `UICollectionView`. So the reason above issue was there is that `UICollectionViewCell` is set to be reused, but I didn't clear the old data up before one cell was dragged out of the reuse queue. I just wrote a custom method: `[self clearData];` for it to be ready for reuse and solved the problem.